# Proguard returned error

Tags: android, proguard, publishing

I get this error when doing export signed application package

```
[2015-02-09 17:22:33 - matriX] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-02-09 17:22:33 - matriX] proguard.ParseException: Expecting opening '{' at '­keepclassmembernames' in line 56 of file 'C:\Users\dani__000\Dropbox\matriXFerran\proguard-project.txt',
[2015-02-09 17:22:33 - matriX]   included from argument number 4
[2015-02-09 17:22:33 - matriX]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:678)
[2015-02-09 17:22:33 - matriX]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
[2015-02-09 17:22:33 - matriX]  at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:141)
[2015-02-09 17:22:33 - matriX]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

and the line is this one:

```
-­keepclassmembernames class * {
  @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the `keepclassmembernames` with a dash: `-`

```
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *; 
}
```